# Ajax Notice - Undefined index: id

Tags: php, ajax

I really need your help to deal with an AJAX request.

```
function detailsmodal(id){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/E-shop2/views/details-model.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'id' : id},
        success: function(returnData){
        jQuery('#details-window').modal('toggle');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("SOmething went wrong");
        }
    });
}
```

php file

```
$id =  $_POST['id'];
$id = (int)$id;
```

For some reason it does not recognize the index id from the post method and I get a notice. Do you have any idea what is the problem and how I can fix it?

Comment: Change this line:   `data: {'id' : id}` to `data: {id : id}`

Comment: In php file check the POSTed value with `isset()`. If your `id` not set properly then the inside block will not execute then you can understand where you make wrong, also enable the error reporting.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I used the isset() check and it does not show a notice. However this $id variable has to hold the id of my products from the database. Basically I'm calling the function detailsmodal like this <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="detailsmodal(<?php echo $products['id']?>)">Details</button>. There is still something wrong with the function detailsmodal, cause it is not passing this id correctly

Answer (score 0):

At Left hand always a varible.So you need to define change variable name in data part.

```
function detailsmodal(sid){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/E-shop2/views/details-model.php",
            type: "POST",
           /*** data: {'id' : id}, // Replace Here {id : id}*/
            data: {id : sid},
            success: function(returnData){
            jQuery('#details-window').modal('toggle');
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("SOmething went wrong");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. So in the php file, should I use                 $sid = $_POST['id']?  I tried it like this, but I get NULL result

Comment: It means you are not get sid in ajax call